# Render each of multiple objects in array with Express in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, object

I have multiple objects in array of locals in my `routes` and would like to render each at the time.

**Example**

```
// routes.js

const routes = {
  path: '/posts/:id',
  view: 'posts',
  locals: [
    {
      id: 'how-to-write-short',
      title: 'How to write short',
      description: 'The art of painting a thousand pictures with just a few words',
      date: '23 Mar 2018',
      issue: '1'
    },
    {
      id: 'the-glamour-of-grammar',
      title: 'The glamour of grammar',
      description: 'A guide to the magic and mystery of practical English',
      date: '01 April 2018',
      issue: '2'
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now, this renders the last objects in array when I visit either link `http://localhost:3000/posts/how-to-write-short` or `http://localhost:3000/posts/the-glamour-of-grammar`.

```
// server.js

const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')

const app = express()

app.set('views', 'src/pages')
app.set('view engine', 'js')
app.engine('js', require('./engine'))

app.get(routes.path, function(req, res) {
    res.render(routes.view, routes.locals)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

What's a better to render each e.g `routes.locals[0]`, `routes.locals[1]`, and ...?

Comment: Your question is not really clear...

Comment: Checkout [ask] and [mcve] for a guide on how to write a good question folks can answer. If I were to bet, I'd say the template or view you're using has some errors and does not treat `locals` as an array. Put that up as well cause I think that'll help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way is search the post id and pass it to the render:

```
app.get(routes.path, (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const post = routes.locals.find(p => p.id === id);
  if (post) {
    res.render(routes.view, post);
  } else {
    res.render(routes.post_not_found_view);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

In your code

```
app.get(routes.path, function(req, res) {
    res.render(routes.view, routes.locals)
})
```

take from req the id and pass it to the res.render. Then you should select only the local that you are interested in and this should do the trick.

```
app.get(routes.path, function(req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const local = routes.locals.filter(local => local.id === id)
    res.render(routes.view, local)
})
```

Hope this will help you.